# Remove image and use CSS instead for data from database using PHP

Tags: php

I have the PHP code as below:

```
 <?php 
                for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
                $checked = ($value['2.Capacity'] == $i) ? ' <img src="img/tick.jpg" width="20px" />' : '';
                echo  '<td>'.$checked.$i.'</td>';
                }
```

**I need:**

I want to remove the `<img src="img/tick.jpg" width="20px" />` to put CSS style `Bold + underlined` I do not know how to fix this.

**Note:**

For the `$value['2.Capacity']` it's data from database, it integer value `1 2 3 4 5`.

Anyone help me please,Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 

            for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
            $checked = ($value['2.Capacity'] == $i) ? ' text-decoration: underline; font-weight: bold;' : '';
            echo  "<td style=$checked>$i</td>";
            }
```

Comment: Thanks it works well now but need to add single quote to `style=$checked` like `style='$checked'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
  $style = ($value['2.Capacity'] == $i) ? 'text-decoration: underline; font-weight: bold;" : ''     ;                         
  echo "<td><span style='$style'>$i</span></td>";
}
```

Comment: Fixed my answer to use `<span>`, not `<style>`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to understand first the Conditional Statement you're using.
You can check out this link for the explanation: http://davidwalsh.name/php-ternary-examples

```
$checked = ($value['2.Capacity'] == $i) ? ' <img src="img/tick.jpg" width="20px" />' : '';
```

This code is something like this:

```
$checked = (conditional statement) ? return true : return false;
```

The anwer of Akhilraj N S and Barmar will satisfy your needs.